# Ruby Wrapper Class results in NameError uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I'm trying to model some UI elements.

I've created a series of classes in `/app/models/wrappers/*`

For this post i'm going to focus on a class called `InputTextVO`

I have:

```
class InputTextVO
...
end
```

> /app/models/wrappers/InputTextVO.rb

When I try and initialize it in my controller I get the following:

> NameError in InputsController#index
>   uninitialized constant InputsController::InputTextVO

```
@ivo = InputTextVO.new
```

RubyMine can locate the class and doesn't report any errors in my controller.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try `@ivo = ::InputTextVO.new`. I thought that everything in `app/models` was already in the autoload path...

Comment: also you should name the file correctly in snake case e.g. `input_text_vo.rb`

Comment: Did you `require` the Ruby file which creates the class?

Answer (score 1):

You must to add a module if you want to create a subdirectory in the model directory. You can do it like this :

```
class Wrappers::InputTextVO
...
end
Wrappers::InputTextVO.new #....
```

It should work.

You can also create a new directory like this `app/wrapper`.